# Need a blank line after last line of table

Tags: php

After description prints I just need a blank line, so that when the table starts again there is some space between entries.....

How can I do that? This is a PHP document

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $searchTerm = $_POST['search'];
    
    $searchArray = array_filter($items, function ($var) use ($searchTerm) {
        return stristr($var->name, $searchTerm);
    });

    echo '<table>';
    foreach ($searchArray as $search) {
        echo '<th> Item Number: <hr> </th> <td>'.$search->item_number.'<td>';
        echo '<tr><th> Name:</th></tr> <td>'.$search->name.'</td>';
        echo '<tr><th> Type:</th></tr> <td>'.$search->type.'</td>';
        echo '<tr><th> Make: </th></tr> <td>'.$search->make.'</tr></td>';
        echo '<tr> <th> Model: </th></tr> <td>'.$search->model.'</tr></td>';
        echo '<tr><th> Brand: </th></tr> <td>'.$search->brand.'</td>';
        echo '<tr><th> Description: </th></tr><td>'.$search->description.'</tr></td>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
```

Comment: Do you need space between the tables?

Comment: Exactly yes if there are multiple entries I want a space between them

Comment: did you try adding empty row `echo '<tr><td></td></tr>';`

Comment: actually, your table structure is not standard, go check the docs again <th>'s should'nt be in with <td>'s

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are talking about [css margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/margin)

Try to add a `margin` to your table:

```
echo '<table style="margin-bottom:1em">';
```